# Implementing Traffic channels on Google Analytics using cid parameter

Tags: google-analytics

Summary: Marketing channels on GA using 'cid' instead of 'utm' parameter in URL

We use Adobe Analytics and hence all traffic channels are configured with 'cid' parameter for all campaign tracking. For ex.

```
cid=ps:Tata_Cliq_Westside_Exact_Apparel:Google:Search_Sok_Tatacliqwestside_E:Apparel-Unisex
```

This parameter is taken by Adobe Analytics and processing rules then give the data under various channels.

How do I use the same setup and implement marketing channels on Google Analytics? I don't want to use utm as a query-string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use View Advanced Filters to rewrite campaign/source data from URL with the help of regexp but I suppose that it would be a very complicated filter and data will only be available in the view where the filter is applied.
If you're using Google Tag Manager you can set up custom javascript variables to extract data from URL and pass it along with Google Analytics tags as pre-set fields for source/campaign/medium etc.